# Firebase Cloud function: how many users can the same function (onCall) serve? With how many resources can it serve them?

Tags: node.js, firebase, function, google-cloud-functions, limit

Hy everyone. I have only one "onCall" firebase function but it is called many times by all users. Every single function can be called 3000 times per second as the documentation says. Since mine needs 5 seconds then would I have 600 calls per second available?

Since my function manipulates images and needs to store them in the tmp folder of the server (or virtual machine). I happened to get an error message telling me that I have exceeded the allowable memory for the function. I fixed the function trying to take up less memory and now it works. My question is this: assuming the memory available for the function is X, and the call requires X / 2 memory, does that mean I can only have two simultaneous function calls (so as not to run out of X memory)?

Also, I'm not sure how much this X is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cloud Functions auto-scale up and down to meet the load. If that is not happening for you, edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks. I have read about it. But I wanted to understand how it worked deeper. Does auto-scale mean that if the function can have maximum memory X every time it "auto-scales" it will still have memory X regardless of whether someone else has previously consumed some of it? Could it be said that every function has memory X "for each call"? Or even if I make 100 calls simultaneously, the function X must not "in total" exceed X as the memory occupied?

Comment: On Cloud Functions only a single instance of your function will ever run in parallel on a single container. So that indeed means your code has the full resources of that container each time it runs.

Comment: ok, perfect. So every time the user A call my function this function is executed with X resources. If in parallel a user B calls the same function this function is executed again with X resources. Thanks!!

Comment: "So every time the user A call my function this function is executed with X resources" => yes. "If in parallel a user B calls the same function this function is executed again with X resources" => yes and there are two scenarios. 1/ If the instance running work of user A is still running, the Cloud Function platform will spin up another instance (totally isolated from the first one). 2/ If the first instance is idle the platform will execute the work of user B on this one. The platform may shut down an instance at any time if it is idle.

Comment: So clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions auto-scale up and down to meet the load.

On Cloud Functions only a single instance of your function will ever run in parallel on a single container. So that indeed means your code has the full resources of that container each time it runs.